# Instantiate a generic type which implements an Interface C#

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I have the following generic type:

```
public class CommandFlow<T> : IFlow where T: IFlow
{
    private T _flow;
    public CommandFlow(T flow)
    {
        _flow= flow;
    }    
}
```

where IFlow has some implementations: StaticFlow, DynamicFlow, CombinedFlow. I want to instantiate the generic type with Active.CreateInstance, so I have the code:

```
var flowType = typeof(CommandFlow<>).MakeGenericType(nominalFlowType);
//nominalFlowType is one of the types: StaticFlow, DynamicFlow, CombinedFlow
```

Then I try to instantiate the generic type:

```
var commandFlow = Activator.CreateInstance(flowType, new object[] {new StaticFlow()});
```

I get the error:

> "Constructor on type 'CommandFlow`1[[DynamicFlow, ...]]' not found"

Comment: I'm assuming that in this case, `nominalFlowType` is of type `StaticFlow`, since that's what you passed to the constructor?

Comment: nominalFlowType can be any of the three implemented flow types: static, dynamic, combined. In this case is DynamicFlow

Comment: So you're (deliberately?) mixing DynamicFlow and StaticFlow ?

Comment: So basically you're trying to mimick this: `new CommandFlow<DynamicFlow>(new StaticFlow(...));` ? Does this work?

Comment: Your code is just short of being complete. Add the declaration of `nominalFlowType` and make sure the whole thing is correct and using the same types/vars (compile before posting).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error indicates that you are trying to construct an object of type `CommandFlow<DynamicFlow>`, so `nominalFlowType` must have been `DynamicFlow`.

As you're trying to pass a `StaticFlow` as a constructor argument, there isn't any constructor that can do this; you'd need to pass a `DynamicFlow` value.